# What is the breaking change criteria with Snyk

Tags: snyk

What is the criteria for choosing what upgrade involves a breaking change at Snyk when it comes to the Fix pull/merge request.

For example, Pillow v8.1.2 to v9.2.0

[image: sample table]

I tried to upgrade the `pillow` version which involves a major upgrade and therefore thought it would  bring a breaking change.

Answer (score 0):

The criteria is whether it's a major upgrade or not. Above example seems to be a bug; it should be a "yes".
(Disclaimer: I work at Snyk and checked and reported it internally).